# Algorithm for traversing all lines in the n×n grid?

Tags: algorithm

Use a two-dimensional array to represent a nxn grid.

```
var grid = new int[n,n];
```

[image: n*n grid]

Note that there are two more diagonal lines.

Comment: It is better to make the grid two dimensional, otherwise, you would need to use mod function ;             var grid = new int[,] {
                {1,2,3},
                {4,5,6},
                {7,8,9}
            };

Comment: You can use two dimensional array for that, and iterate easily

Comment: Why complicate? Make a 2D grid.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more suitable for most people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i will solve this problem. I will make so.

Create extension method for Int[] (So, you can create your own class. But it's another way. I want to show light waight solution)

```
    public static class IntAsMatrixExtensions {

        public const int MatrixColumsCount = 3;

        public static int At(this int[] matrix, int i, int j)
        {
            return matrix[i * MatrixColumsCount + j];
        }

        public static int[] Create()
        {
            var grid = new int[MatrixColumsCount*MatrixColumsCount] {
                1,2,3,
                4,5,6,
                7,8,9
            };

            return grid;
        }
    }
```

Then first you should print matrix:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < IntAsMatrixExtensions.MatrixColumsCount; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < IntAsMatrixExtensions.MatrixColumsCount; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(grid.At(i, j));
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Then print transponated matrix:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < IntAsMatrixExtensions.MatrixColumsCount; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < IntAsMatrixExtensions.MatrixColumsCount; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(grid.At(j, i)); //!!! i and j is swithed
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Then print diag:

```
        //Print diag
        for(int i = 0; i < IntAsMatrixExtensions.MatrixColumsCount; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(grid.At(i, i)); //!!! i and j is swithed
        }
```

Then print inverse diag:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < IntAsMatrixExtensions.MatrixColumsCount; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(grid.At(i, IntAsMatrixExtensions.MatrixColumsCount - i - 1)); //!!! i and j is swithed
        }
```

Here is example on fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/pyX31r

Comment: This is the right answer. It should stand up to dimension changes.

Comment: Is it correct answer for you? If so, you can shoose mark answer as Right.

Comment: Excuse me, that is correct variant: https://dotnetfiddle.net/z4yKyh